# jQuery extension data persistence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering how to share data between methods in a jQuery extension, so when I call the `refresh` method, it is able to use the `plugin` and `options` variables defined in `init`.

There is more than one of these controls per page.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                defaultText: "Rating",
                maxRating: 5,
            };

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var plugin = $(this);

                main($(plugin), options);
            });
        },

        refresh: function() {
            // I would like to be able to use the 'options' and 'plugin' variables defined in the init method
        }
    };

    function main(plugin, option) {
        // do main code stuff
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the data on the element itself, then access it per element.

```
(function ($) {

var methods = { // should probably expose this object in some way so it can be extended by other develoeprs or so that defaults can be changed

    defaults : {
        defaultText: "Rating",
        maxRating: 5,
    },

    init : function (options) {

        options = $.extend({}, methods.defaults, options);

        this.data("myPlugin", options);

        return this.each(function () {

            main($(this), options);

        });
    },

    refresh : function () {

        return this.each(function(){

            var options = $(this).data("myPlugin");

        });
                // I would like to be able to use the 'options' and 'plugin' variables defined in the init method
    }
};

function main(plugin, option) {

    // do main code stuff

}

})(jQuery);
```

I'm not sure why you would want access to the plugin var, you should already have access to the element that the refresh method is called on.

Comment: So in the refresh method, $(this) would be the plugin anyway?

Comment: Depending on how you are calling the method, yes.

Comment: Interesting. How would the method need to be called?

Comment: yes, for example, `$.fn.myPlugin = function(method) { if ( methods[method] ) methods[method].apply( this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) ) };`

Comment: OK. So as long as the method has been 'apply'ed as it were, $(this) within the method will be the same as in other methods also 'apply'ed?

Comment: Yes, with `.apply` or `.call`